# Apache not working

Tags: apache2, phpmyadmin

I dont know how to fix this error:

> apache2: Syntax error on line 238 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could
>   not open configuration file /etc/phpmymin/apache2.conf: No such file
>   or directory

Comment: Welcome to AskUbntu. What is the output of this command: `ls -la /etc/phpmymin/apache2.conf`?

Answer (score 0):

Apache is looking for an included config file which it can't find (`phpmymin` looks like a typo to me). Edit `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and either fix the error, or remove line 238 completely to allow apache to start.

It would be helpful if you gave more details about the procedure you followed to arrive at this error. If, for instance, you were following an on-line tutorial or document, posting a reference to it would be great, this allows people to see where things may have gone wrong.

Comment: wow, thank you I did not see the error, the command I entered was "sudo service apache2 restart" and it come u with that error